# Changing element in a dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am going to clean the data in a 4 * 4 dataframe in Python, with elements 'a' and '?' in it. I want to replace '?' by NA.

In R, I write:

```
for (i in 1:4){
    DATA[DATA[,i]=='?',i]=NA}
```

When I have tried to write in Python:

```
for i in range(3):
    DATA[DATA.iloc[:,i]=='?'].iloc[:,i]=np.nan
```

I cannot change anything when I use Python. How should I write the command? Thanks.

Comment: in R: `Data[Data=="?"] <- NA`. You don't need a for loop. `.replace` in python is the way to go as outlined below. Generally, when a vectorized solution is available, loops are not advised.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can directly use `DATA.replace({'?':None})`

Comment: May I further ask what is the meaning of the brackets? I mean the function of each of them. I am not familiar with this writing method. Thanks.

Comment: DATA-> this is your dataframe object.
.replace() -> is a pandas dataframe class function
DATA.replace()-> you are calling this function for DATA object
{'?': None}-> this is a dictionary notation mapping '?' to None. 
so in essence DATA.replace({'?':None} is request to replace '?' with None in DATA object

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, we can do this without a loop as well

```
DATA[1:4][DATA[1:4] == '?'] <- NA
```

Comment: @Danny The `[]` can take a row index, column index separated by `,` i.e. `df1[2:4, 2]` gives the rows 2 to 4 from the 2nd column or similarly `df1[1:3, 2:5]` gives a subset of dataset with columns 2 to 5 and rows `1:3`.  Using index without a `,` by default will be evaluated as column index.  so, here `DATA[1:4]` is selecting the first four columns

Comment: But what about the double bracket after DATA[1:4]? I mean the used to be the criteria.

Comment: @Danny Here, `DATA[1:4]` is a subset of columns, then we do a comparison (`==`) to get a logical matrix (`DATA[1:4] == '?'`  This logical matrix (TRUE values) are used to subset the `DATA[1:4]` i.e. `DATA[1:4][logicalmatrix]` and set those elements to `NA` which corresponds to the TRUE